# Beaglebone Black Persistent Internet Over USB - Debian Image 2016-05.13 am335x_evm.sh

Tags: beagleboneblack

My internet over usb used to just work on my BBB but now every time I boot I have to manually add

```
route add default gw 192.168.7.1
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

I as following [this](http://www.alexschimp.com/beaglebone-black-persistent-usb-internet-connection/) guide but in `/opt/scripts/boot/am335x_evm.sh`

I can no longer find

```
/sbin/ifconfig usb0 192.168.7.2 netmask 255.255.255.252
/usr/sbin/udhcpd -S /etc/udhcpd.conf`
```

so I can add `/sbin/route add default gw 192.168.7.1 metric 1`

Where can I add this line?

edit: Host computer is windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel maintainers update the kernel for that chip-family *daily*, so you should `git pull` that /opt directory you mentioned and then run the `./kernel_update` in /opt/path/to/tools.

All of the directories on the BBB that can be updated in this manner are on https://github.com/RobertCNelson.

ps. I also updated my device tree files.